# jquery templates with a JSON call for the template and data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-templates

I'm running into an interesting issue with jQuery templates. I want to be able to get a dynamic template via JSON (which I have working) and then data to match that template via JSON, which is where my problem lies.

Here is what I have for the template stuff:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GenerateAdminTemplate", "Home", new { area = "" })', function (data) {
    if (data.Success) {
        adminListTemplate = data.Result;
        $("#adminListHeader").html(data.Header);
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GenerateAdminSheet", "Home", new {area = ""})', function (dataz) {
            if (dataz.Success) {
                $("#templateListing").text(data.Result);
                $("#markupBeforeTemplateListing").text(dataz.Result);
                var myTemplate = $.template(null, data.Result);

                //var arr = [
                //  { Name: "User1", Administrator: "yes", Supervisor: "no", User: "yes" },
                //  { Name: "User2", Administrator: "yes", Supervisor: "no", User: "no" }
                //];

                var arr = dataz.Result;

                $.tmpl(myTemplate, arr).appendTo("#adminListBody");
            } else {

            }
        });
    } else {
    }
});
```

The template itself comes back and is successful. When I uncomment the hardcoded array (arr) and use that instead of the returned value, the table appears EXACTLY as I expect it to. When I use the JSON returned data however, I get something that looks like this (I removed the username, which is the blank space on the left):

[image: jQueryTemplateResult]

The data that comes back from the JSON request is 100% identical to the "hardcoded" array (arr). I've used Beyond Compare on the results and they are 100% identical.

For thoroughness: Here is the code that returns the JSon Data:

```
public JsonResult GenerateAdminSheet()
{
    bool success = false;
    String errorMessage = String.Empty;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


    try
    {
        List<String> listOfUsersAndRoles = new List<String>();

        using (DataUtilityEntities data = new DataUtilityEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataUtilityConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            List<User> users = data.Users.ToList();

            foreach (User u in users)
            {
                List<Role> rolesUserBelongsTo = data.UserInRoles.Where(o => o.UserId == u.UserId).Select(p => p.Role).ToList();

                CustomDictionary allRoles = new CustomDictionary();

                //add the username as the first entry in the dictionary
                allRoles.Add("Name", u.Username);

                List<Role> allRolesList = data.Roles.ToList();

                foreach (Role r in allRolesList)
                {
                    allRoles.Add(String.Format("{0}", r.Name), rolesUserBelongsTo.Exists(p => p.Name == r.Name) ? "yes" : "no");
                }

                listOfUsersAndRoles.Add(allRoles.ToString());
            }

        }

        //We have the list of the objects to pass back, now we just need to format them so they will work properly
        result.Append("[");
        foreach (String item in listOfUsersAndRoles)
        {
            result.Append(item);
            if (listOfUsersAndRoles.Last() != item)
                result.Append(", ");
        }
        result.Append("]");

        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        success = false;
        errorMessage = String.Format("@There was an error: {0}{1}", e.Message, e.InnerException == null ? String.Empty : String.Format("@({0})", e.InnerException.Message));
    }

    return Json(new { Success = success, ErrorMessage = errorMessage, Result = result.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

CustomDictionary is just an override of the .ToString():

```
public override string ToString()
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    result.Append("{ ");

    foreach (var pair in this)
    {
        result.Append(String.Format("{0}: \"{1}\"{2}", pair.Key, pair.Value, this.Last().Key == pair.Key ? String.Empty : ", "));
    }

    result.Append(" }");
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Is there something Im missing when the result comes back from the JSon Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue with the help of a colleague.
As it turns out, the Template won't take a string value as an object, so you need to parse it as a JSON object:

```
var arr = dataz.Result.toString();

var obj = $.parseJSON(arr);
```

However, one thing to note, the way I did this was slightly incorrect and the `$.parseJSON` method would throw an exception due to "malformed" json.

What I have above:

```
[{Name: "user", Administrator: "yes" ... }, {Name: "user2", ...}]
```

won't work, it needs to be:

```
[{"Name": "user", "Administrator": "yes" ...}, {"Name": "user2", ...}]
```